# Azure licensing and MFA for guests

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

Good afternoon,

I am confused about licensing in Azure and I am hoping someone here can help me understand. Regrettably, Microsoft was not particularly helpful when I contacted sales.

I have an on-prem AD synced with Azure AD cloud (free edition). We have a number of guests (for purposes of this question, 10) for Teams access, and I would like to implement an MFA requirement for them. It appears Azure AD premium licensing may be required to do this. If it is, does each guest user need an Azure AD Premium P1 or P2 license assigned (so 10 Azure AD Px licenses)? Or do I just need one for the administrator?

I'm finding the licensing portion confusing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The licensing agreement requires that every user using Azure MFA needs at least a Premium P1 license. (See [related discussion](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2304327-azure-ad-premium-p1-for-mfa).)

If you are using the free version with security defaults enabled, then you can use a [subset of the MFA features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults) and the users can only authenticate using the Authenticator app. But you won't be able to use conditional access or have MFA turned on for some users and not others.

Comment: Thank you. To confirm, each of the guest users (only active in tenant for a single team for collaboration) would need to be assigned a P1/P2 license (so 10 licenses at $6/9 per license/month)? Thank you again.